# Scrolling text gets negated in static control (C++ WinAPI)

Tags: c++, winapi, scroll, controls

I have some weird control,

```
CreateWindowEx(!tset&USE?WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW:0,
tset&USE?"static":"edit",0,WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|
(!tset&USE?ES_MULTILINE|ES_WANTRETURN|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|WS_VSCROLL //when it's edit
:SS_NOTIFY|SS_EDITCONTROL),5,60,390,474,hwnd,HMENU(10),0,0); //when it's static
SetWindowSubclass(GetDlgItem(hwnd,10),tset&USE?BOR:NoMenu,0,0);
```

whose everything depends on whether themes are active. Here `tset` is an instance of `enum` type for bit flags. **Everything is fine except scrolling when the control is in static mode.** It wasn't receiving `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` messages, I made it receive them in the following way:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK BOR(HWND hwnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wp,LPARAM lp,UINT_PTR,DWORD_PTR)
{
    if(msg==WM_MOUSEMOVE&&GetDlgCtrlID(hwnd)==10)
    {
        POINT x{LOWORD(lp),HIWORD(lp)}; ClientToScreen(hwnd,&x);
        RECT rc; GetWindowRect(hwnd,&rc); if(PtInRect(&rc,x)&&GetCapture()!=hwnd){SetCapture(hwnd); hwnd3=SetFocus(hwnd);}
        if(!PtInRect(&rc,x)&&GetCapture()==hwnd){ReleaseCapture(); SetFocus(hwnd3);} //hwnd3 is an instance of HWND defined in global scope, for giving focus back
    }
    if(msg==WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
    {
        RECT rc; GetWindowRect(GetParent(hwnd),&rc);
        HRGN x; GetWindowRgn(GetParent(hwnd),x);
        ScrollWindowEx(hwnd,0,short(HIWORD(wp)),0,0,x,&rc,SW_INVALIDATE|SW_ERASE);
        ShowWindow(GetParent(hwnd),SW_HIDE); ShowWindow(GetParent(hwnd),SW_SHOW);
        SetFocus(hwnd);
        return 1;
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd,msg,wp,lp);
}
```

Now when mouse enters client area of my control, if it's in static mode, it captures mouse and gets focus. So it intercepts `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` messages in its subclass callback function and I can scroll my control in the static mode. Here's the exact problem: few milliseconds later, **right after its text is scrolled,** the window somehow updates itself to its initial unscrolled state. And my efforts get negated. Is it clear why it behaves like this, and how to fix that?

@Edit: Why don't I simply add `WS_VSCROLL` to its static version? Because it has `SS_NOTIFY` style and I need it to respond to `WM_COMMAND` messages somehow else. This is why I tried scrolling it manually.

@Update: [image]

Here in both screenshots the text length is the same. When the control is in edit state, its vertical scrollbar is proper. But when it's in static state the vertical scrollbar doesn't match the actual text length. Besides, the scrollbar is always at the same size and same position independent from text length and it's also unscrollable. Why may be the reason of it behaving like this?

**@Update:** Thanks to [@enhzflep's comment,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65728409/scrolling-text-gets-negated-in-static-control-c-winapi?noredirect=1#comment116214109_65728409) problem is easily solved some other way.

Comment: What about using `SS_NOTIFY` prevents you from using `WH_VSCROLL`? They do not have overlapping bits in their values, so you CAN use them together.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I observed that clicking onto the client area of the contol, including its scrollbar, sends a `WM_COMMAND` message. And my program hides some controls and shows some other controls when it receives `WM_COMMAND` with `STN_CLICKED` and I need it not to happen when I use the scrollbar.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah you wrote `WH_VSCROLL`, sorry I misread it as `WM_VSCROLL`. I haven't thought of hooking vertical scrolling yet. I'll try it and update here. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I meant the [`WS_VSCROLL` style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) (and yes, there is a [`WM_VSCROLL` message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-vscroll)). You can use `WS_VSCROLL` with `SS_NOTIFY` on a `static` control. A lot of different notifications use `WM_COMMAND`. But clicking on a scrollbar should not send `STN_CLICKED`. My point is, if you enable `WS_VSCROLL`, you should not have to scroll manually at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried commenting out many lines and figured out that the problem might be at 2 spots. It's either because I `return 1;` from `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` or simply because static controls cannot be scrolled. I removed subclassing, made the control like `CreateWindow("static",0,WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|SS_EDITCONTROL|WS_VSCROLL,5,60,390,474,hwnd,HMENU(10),0,0);` and its scrollbar is still passive. The question now is, can static controls be scrolled at all?

Comment: @RemyLebeau However, something like `CreateWindow("edit",0,WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_MULTILINE|ES_WANTRETURN|WS_VSCROLL,5,60,390,474,hwnd,HMENU(10),0,0);` perfectly works. So maybe the problem was at it being static at all?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry for posting multiple comments, but this is the last for now. If static controls cannot be scrolled when text size exceeds client area size (I assume this because static controls is some kind of edit control with `WS_DISABLED` style), then I might use `SetWindowPos()` for both control and its parent to extend their height. Or I can think about an another workaround, maybe splitting texts to few static controls and adding a button to turn pages.

Comment: Seems interesting that one of them is clearly wrapping the text and the other isn't. With this in mind, the size of the scroll-bars doesn't seem off to me, since the dark image is wrapped, there will be a larger number of lines and and thus, a smaller thumb. Since it appears to be the static that's misbehaving, why not use an edit control all the time, just toggling its read-only flag? I.e, using the EM_SETREADONLY message.

Comment: @enhzflep That actually worked! I don't know why I didn't think about it earlier, thank you :) Problem solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the interests of removing the question from the Unanswered list, I'll repeat and expand upon one of the comments.

Looking at the images, we can immediately see a clear difference in the way they're each presented. The left image has each line starting with a different character, while the right image always starts with the same character. They also have very differently sized thumbs in the scroll-bar.

Since the problems seem to be stemming from trying to use two different controls to achieve essentially the same task, I'd suggest always using an edit control. (this is the one that appears to behave nicely, and is the one that doesn't wrap the text)

Rather than use two different types of control, I suggest just toggling the read-only flag. With luck (!) the only difference now will be the way mouse and keyboard messages are handled - hopefully you'll get similar behaviour and appearance with such an approach.
The message I'm thinking of that will achieve this is `EM_SETREADONLY`.

Although the question has been successful answered, I can't find reference in the Microsoft docs to support my theories, thus used language like 'hopefully'.

Comment: They both contain the text with the same length because that's a copy paste of the same string, ~2500 characters. But wrapping is different indeed. Anyway, it behaves as intended now, so I marked this answer as accepted. Thanks again